# "type object unsubscriptable" error, but only in script

Tags: python, split

For an experiment on sentence comprehension, I have prepared a set of files, each consisting of a list lines that go like this:

1 14 2 "experimental sentence"

The "1 14 2" is a reference number. For the purposes of the experiment, I have to randomize the sentences in each of the files, with the constraint that no two adjacent sentences can have the same third number. That is

1 14 2

1 14 3

is an acceptable sequence, but

1 14 2

1 13 2

is not.

I wrote a function `line_randomizer(filename)` that randomizes all the lines in `filename` and puts them on `buffer = []`, and defined a `limit` variable with the number of lines in `buffer`. Then, I wrote the following function:

```
def checker():
    counter = 0
    while counter < limit:
       next = counter + 1
       val1 = buffer[counter].split(" ")[2]
       val2 = buffer[next].split(" ")[2]
       if int(val1) == int(val2):
          print("bad sequence; starting new randomization")
          line_randomizer(filename)
       else:
          print("continue checking")
       counter = counter + 1
```

When I run this on the python interpreter (called from a shell), everything works fine, but when I write the exact same code on a .py script, I get this error.

```
val1 = buffer[counter].split(" ")[2]
TypeError: 'type' object is unsubscriptable
```

Why does this only happen on a script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you defining `buffer`? `buffer` is a type as well, so if it isn't properly defined in your function then it will look at the built-in `buffer` and then return that error.

Answer (score 0):

In the command line session, you must have `buffer` set to something.

In your script, however, nobody sets `buffer`, so it uses the built-in name which is a type object, which is, like most types, unsubscriptable.